# Adjust minipage height with \adjustbox

Tags: minipage, adjustbox

I want to align three images like this, only specifying the total height, like this:

```
 ______   _________
|      | |         |
|      | |         |
|      | |_________|
|      |  _________
|      | |         |
|______| |_________|
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=10cm]{img/detectors-field.pdf}%
\adjustbox{height=10cm}{%
    \begin{minipage}{10cm}%
        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{img/coax_pic.jpg} \\
        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{img/bege_pic.jpg}%
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\end{document}
```

But I get this result:

[image: bad-result]

Why doesn't `\adjustbox` work in this case? What's the correct way to achieve the positioning I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some clarification by the OP, I have revised my answer to suit.

The syntax is

```
\makecomposite{<left-img>}{<top-right-img>}{<bottom-right-img>}{<composite-height>}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\makecomposite[4]{%
  \savestack\imgstack{\stackengine{0pt}{\includegraphics[width=1in]{#3}}
        {\belowbaseline[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1in]{#2}}}
        {O}{l}{F}{F}{S}}%
  \savestack\imgcomposite{\scalerel{\includegraphics{#1}}{\imgstack}}%
  \scaleto{\imgcomposite}{#4}
}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\makecomposite{example-image-a}{example-image-b}{example-image-10x16}{5cm}

\makecomposite{example-image-a}{example-image-b}{example-image-golden}{3cm}

\makecomposite{example-image-a}{example-image-b}{example-image-c}{3cm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! However, I'm wondering if there exists a solution that lets everything scale correctly with `myheight`...

Comment: @LuigiPertoldi Define "correctly".  i.e., Are not my scales correct?  Does "correct" have anything to do with the gap size?

Comment: @LuigiPertoldi If the goal is to eliminate the vertical gap between images B and C, see the **ADDENDUM** to my answer.

Comment: With "scales correctly with `myheight`" I mean that the relative proportions of each image are preserved when changing `myheight` (and then one does not have to tweak with the widths of B and C). The feature that I'm looking for, that is missing in your addendum, is that the horizontal widths of B and C must be the same.

Comment: The theoretical problem with what you are trying to automate @LuigiPertoldi is that a "solution" is not possible for all conceivable image aspect ratios for the three images. You need at least one other constraint or variable relaxation of a constraint in order to automate it. This might involve cropping of one or more images, or a non-full-width image if that is not possible. So you need to specify your problem and potentially allowable "fixes".

Comment: If one declares a "row" height and states that each "column" must be made of images with the same width then the solution of the problem is unique, no other degrees of freedom are left unspecified. Give me a counterexample if I'm wrong.

Comment: Take for example the last image in your answer, you can clearly see that there exists (only) one value of width for B and C that satisfy the requirements.

Comment: What I was trying in my first attempt was to first set the same width for B and C and then resize both of them with `\adjustbox`, but apparently `\adjustbox` doesn't behave as I expected...

Comment: @LuigiPertoldi Actually, the addendum worked, other for the fact that I specified distinct widths of the stacked images.  I have placed it into a macro to better demonstrate it.

Comment: That's right, I didn't notice it. That macro is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This only works if the two images on the right have the same width (you can use `width` to equalize them first.

In the example I use both `width` and `height` to get different aspect ratios.

The idea is to scale the image on the left and the combination of the two images on the right at the same height, then resize the whole to the desired target height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\resizebox{!}{6cm}{% 6cm is the target height
  \resizebox{!}{1cm}{% 1cm is arbitrary
    \includegraphics[height=10cm,width=4cm]{example-image}%
  }%
  \resizebox{!}{1cm}{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[height=6cm,width=8cm]{example-image}\\
    \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=8cm]{example-image}
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\caption{Three images}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to fill a target width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{% 0.8\textwidth is the target width
  \resizebox{!}{1cm}{% 1cm is arbitrary
    \includegraphics[height=10cm,width=4cm]{example-image}%
  }%
  \resizebox{!}{1cm}{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[height=6cm,width=8cm]{example-image}\\
    \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=8cm]{example-image}
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\caption{Three images}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```